# iOS Simulator Cannot Read the Health Data I Saved

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, healthkit

I have created an app to save & read some running & walking workout data to HealthKit.
I managed to save the data, and view it on the simulator's Health app, but when I try to read the data, sample count is 0. I'd appreciate if someone help me out with this.

Xcode 12.5.1 / iOS 14.5

```
func AuthenticateHealthKit() {

  print("AuthenticateHealthKit")

  let typesToShare: Set = [
    HKQuantityType.workoutType()
  ]

  let typesToRead: Set = [
    HKQuantityType.workoutType(),
    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!,
    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height)!,
  ]

  healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: typesToShare, read: typesToRead) { (success, error) in
    if !success {
      fatalError("Error requesting authorization from health store: \(String(describing: error)))")
    } else {
      print("Authenticated!")
    }
  }

}
```

```
func SaveData() {

  let configuration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
  configuration.activityType = .running
  configuration.locationType = Int.random(in: 0..<2) == 0 ? .indoor : .outdoor

  let startDate = now - (86400 * 60.0)
  let duration = 120.0
  let endDate = startDate + duration
  let quantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.kilocalorie(), doubleValue: 20.0)
  let distance = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.meter(), doubleValue: 1200)

  let workout = HKWorkout(
    activityType: configuration.activityType, start: startDate, end: endDate, duration: duration,
    totalEnergyBurned: quantity, totalDistance: distance,
    metadata: [HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout: true])

  healthStore.save(workout) { success, _ in

    if success {
      print("SAVED WORKOUT!!!")
    } else {
      print("COULD NOT SAVE WORKOUT!!!")
    }

  }

}
```

```
func ReadData() {

  let start = now - (86400 * 60.0)
  let end = now
  let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: start, end: end, options: [])
  print("start : \(start)")

  guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
    print("No data available!")
    return
  }

  guard
    let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(
      forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)
  else {
    fatalError("*** This method should never fail ***")
  }

  let query = HKSampleQuery(
    sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit),
    sortDescriptors: nil
  ) {
    query, results, error in

    guard let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
      print("Error")
      return
    }

    for sample in samples {
      print("sample : \(sample.quantity) \(sample.quantityType)")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      print("Update UI : \(samples.count)")
    }
  }

    healthStore.execute(query)

}
```

**Here is the output of *ReadData* method**

```
start : 2021-08-14 21:38:35 +0000
Authenticated!
Update UI : 0
```

**Following are the Health App data & permissions (all on simulator)**

[image: Health Data & Permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing workouts but wanting to read distance walking+running. Saving a distance property on workouts does not save a distance walking+running sample. You need to create a sample of that type, request auth for it, and save and associate with a workout using addSamples method on HKHealthStore.

It's much better to use an HKWorkoutBuilder and it's beginCollection/add/endCollection/finishWorkout methods which will create a proper HKWorkout object for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have managed to save the data with the help of your suggestion.Below is the updated code for those who would come across the same question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to save data that I can read with the **ReadData** method (look at the original question). This is the new **SaveData** method :

```
let now = Date()

func SaveData() {

        let configuration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
        configuration.activityType = .running
        configuration.locationType = Int.random(in: 0..<2) == 0 ? .indoor : .outdoor

        let builder = HKWorkoutBuilder(healthStore: healthStore, configuration: configuration, device: .local())

        let sample = HKCumulativeQuantitySample(type: HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)!, quantity: HKQuantity.init(unit: HKUnit.meter(), doubleValue: 1230), start: now - 3600, end: now)

        builder.add([sample]) { success, error in

            guard success else {
                print("Error!")
                return
            }

            print("Added Sample")

        }

    }
```